# Gather all other vectors in a list and combine into one vector

Tags: r

Consider the following list:

```
rows <- structure(list(`1` = 1:40, `2` = 41:79, `3` = 80:118, `4` = 119:157, 
           `5` = 158:196, `6` = 197:235, `7` = 236:274, `8` = 275:313, 
           `9` = 314:352, `10` = 353:392), 
      .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

I am currently working on writing a loop (indexed by `i in (1:10)`) in which I would like to generate two variables.

The first one would be `rows[[i]]`. For example, when `i <- 1`,

```
> rows[[i]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
[40] 40
```

How do I generate a second vector which consists of all other values in `rows` (i.e., when `i <- 1`, this would spit out `41:392`)? My thought was to use `row_list[[setdiff(1:length(rows), i)]]`, and indeed,

```
> setdiff(1:length(rows), i)
[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

as I would expect it to be, but

```
> rows[[setdiff(1:length(rows), i)]]
Error in rows[[setdiff(1:length(rows), i)]] : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

I know the list structure seems really clumsy, but I would like to keep the list as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
myFunc <- function(i) setdiff(unlist(rows), rows[[i]])
```

to extract the set difference of all elements from the remaining list elements. The reason your code fails is that `rows[[<vector>]]` attempts to implement a recursive index on a list that is only 1 level deep. This form of indexing can be quite useful in deeply nested lists, but is not needed here.

To see how it works, try `rows[[c(1, 2)]]` and `rows[[c(2, 1)]]` to extract vectors of length 1 containing the first element from list elements 1 and 2 respectively. The  "Recursive (list-like) objects" section of the help file `?"["` provides additional details.